# Register multiple iOS apps with differently punctuated names?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, developer-program

I plan to secure an iOS app name with a hyphen in it (My-App). However should my application take off, I can foresee competitors coming in and muddying the App Store with lookalikes (My App, MyApp, My—-App, etc).

Many of these lookalikes are available to be registered. What is the best strategy for preventing this problem?

I have a trademark with the hyphen but it seems to be a grey area as to whether or not it covers multiple punctuations. The US Patent Office rule is that competition trademarks infringe on each other when they cause material consumer confusion. However this isn’t necessarily true of the App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register your app with multiple names.

In the keywords section, you can put alternative names for your app which will help raise your app for those searches.

Infringements on your trademark by other apps can be reported at
https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstorenotices/.

Comment: Great, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks